# What is the Difference between Action Methods of MagicalRecord in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, actionmethod

Please explain the Difference between below mentioned methods.

```
- (void)save:  
- (void)saveOnlySelfAndWait;    
- (void)saveToPersistentStoreAndWait;
```

**Note:** Some one have posted answer of this question but i am not satisfied with that answer so can anyone please share proper and simple answer.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @JohnSaunders if you know the magical record difference between above method please clear me out.

Comment: If I knew the answer, then I would answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking and searching lot i got answer ...

I acknowledge that these methods aren't documented very well. However, they follow with the Core Data nested context model fairly well.

With MagicalRecord don't use `save:` on an`NSManagedObjectContext`. MagicalRecord has all those extra error handling, logging and completion handlers built in. You want to use those.

You seem to know where data needs to go (from one context to the root). It depends on your hierarchy as to which save method you need to use. If you are only one level deep (ie. in a child context of the defaultContext), `saveOnlySelfAndWait` will save to the`defaultContext`. Otherwise,`saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` will traverse the hierarchy for you, all the way to the data store.

The`andWait` methods are blocking calls. The calls with completion a handler are not. These are fairly straight forward in their use.

Comment: In other words : MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait will **save** synchronously NSManagedObject in the **object space**, MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait will **persist** synchronously the objects in your **data store**. _Moreover MR_save: method is deprecated and will be removed in next release._

Comment: I wish I could get some point ;) Never mind, glad to have helped !